# Comparing smoothing algorithms in R

Tags: raster, r, smoothing, differences

I am comparing smoothing algorithms in `R`. More specifically, the `raster.gaussian.smooth` from the `spatialEco` package and the `focal` from the `terra` package. Visually, the results look similar but the pixel values are way different. It seems that `raster.gaussian.smooth` rescales the data or something. In the picture below, the first layer is my original raster, the second is the result after using `raster.gaussian.smooth` and the third is the result from `terra`'s `focal`:

[image: differences]

How can I stop `raster.gaussian.smooth` from rescaling (or whatever it does) the data? is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
library(terra)
library(spatialEco)

r = rast("path/tirs.tif")

# spatialEco
smoothed = spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth(r, sigma = 0.5 * 350)

# terra focal
gf <- focalMat(r, 0.5*350, "Gauss")
r_gf <- focal(r, w = gf)
```

Here is the raster I am using:

```
new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "D:\\PhD\\Lancaster\\point_spread_function\\london\\2018\\tirs.tif", 
datanotation = "FLT8S", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = c(rows = 256L), blockcols = c(cols = 256L), 
driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", 
values = logical(0), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, 
fromdisk = TRUE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), haveminmax = FALSE, 
min = NA, max = NA, band = 1L, unit = "", names = "B10_median"), 
legend = new(".RasterLegend", type = character(0), values = logical(0), 
    color = logical(0), names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), 
title = character(0), extent = new("Extent", xmin = 509600, 
    xmax = 550500, ymin = 161700, ymax = 196100), rotated = FALSE, 
rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
NULL), ncols = 409L, nrows = 344L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs"), 
history = list(), z = list())
```

Comment: We don't have your TIFF file to try this, but have you read the documentation for possible differences (which might be in the detail) or tried something simple like a matrix that is all zero except for a single "one" pixel in the middle of you want to investigate empirically to compare with the documentation?

Comment: @Spacedman I attached the raster I'm using when I posted the question. No I didn't create the simple matrix you said. I'll do it now

Comment: I don't see an attached raster. The last line of your post creates a raster with all missing values which results in all missing values when processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different focal sizes for the Gaussian weights. The `terra::focalMat` function is resulting in an 11x11 matrix whereas, since you are not providing an “n” argument to `spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth` the default is using a 5x5 matrix. If you define the matrix size so that they match the results are quite a bit closer.

I do not know what the focalMat function is doing to derive the Gaussian matrix but, you do get different results with different rasters whereas, the `spatialEco::gaussian.matrix` function (under the hood of raster.gaussian.smooth) returns a consistent symmetric Gaussian matrix explicitly based on the defined sigma and size.

```
library(terra)
library(spatialEco)

 r <- rast(ncols=578, nrows=449, nlyrs=1, xmin=504400, xmax=562200, 
           ymin=155700, ymax=200600, names=c('B10_median'), 
           crs='EPSG:27700')
    r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

# Matrices based on how you are defining them
( gm <- round(focalMat(r, 350*0.5, "Gauss"),10) )
( gse <- round(gaussian.kernel(sigma = 0.5 * 350),10) )

# If raster.gaussian.smooth matrix is the same as focalMat with focal
spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth(r, sigma = 0.5 * 350, n=nrow(gm))
focal(r, w = gm)
```

Comment: I'll try the `spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth` and compare the results with the `focalMat`. For the latter, I can't set the dimensions of the matrix, it's automatically 11x11. I'll post the results by editing my answer.

Comment: Pretty similar results with the `focalMat`. So as you said, I had to define the `n` parameter in the function `spatialEco::raster.gaussian.smooth`